# django gunicorn workers vs theads vs other possibilities

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

My app in `django` with `gunicorn` and I am kinda new to `gunicorn`. My app is heavy on IO, not so much on memory and CPU, essentially a thread has to save a or serve a big file (from few MB to few GB) from storage. Currently because of this the workers run out while there is no load on CPU or memory or even the HDD. By default has a config file for gunicorn that looks like this:

```
import os

daemon = True
workers = 5

# default localhost:8000
bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"

# Pid
pids_dir = '/opt/pids'
pidfile = os.path.join(pids_dir, 'app.pid')

# for file upload, we need a longer timeout value (default is only 30s, too short)
timeout = 7200

limit_request_line = 8190
```

I am not sure about how to configure the workers and threads etc for my work load. let me provide more details:

1. We run "a few VMs" of 2 CPUs/8GB RAM.
2. python is 2.7 we are on the way to upgrade to 3.7, but for now is 2.7
3. I already tried adding `threads` with different values (1 to 6), but it does not seem to work.
4. The traffic on the app is heavy in general hundreds of users online at any time and more than 100Mbps most of the time.

Can someone please help explain what I can do?

EDIT1:tried to change to gevent, but do not know how to do that. after installed gevent via pip:

```
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]: Failed to read config file: /opt/app/conf/gunicorn.conf
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]:   File "/opt/app-pro-server-7.0.13/app/thirdpart/gunicorn-19.8.1-py2.7.egg
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]:     execfile_(filename, cfg, cfg)
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]:   File "/opt/app-pro-server-7.0.13/app/thirdpart/gunicorn-19.8.1-py2.7.egg
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]:     return execfile(fname, *args)
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]:   File "/opt/conf/gunicorn.conf", line 5
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]:     worker-class = gevent
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]:                ^
Apr 25 07:31:33 web-app1 app.sh[16179]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Apr 25 07:31:38 web-app1 app.sh[16179]: Error:App failed to start
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "workers run out while there is no load"

Comment: @MarkAWard I meant there is no CPU load or memory  heavy RAM usage. Then IO usage would be around 20% of capacity or less. I mean as in the server is not overloaded

Comment: i dont understand what your issue is right now but this may be a useful article https://medium.com/building-the-system/gunicorn-3-means-of-concurrency-efbb547674b7

Comment: @MarkAWard How can I change to gevent? I have tried directives like this in my file and they are not recognized `worker-class = gevent` and `worker-connections=1000`. even when gevent was already instaled via pip.

Comment: personally i have never set the worker class in the conf file, but when invoking gunicorn i have done so like `gunicorn -k gevent -w 8 -b unix:/tmp/app.sock wsgi:app`